# jQuery plugin only accessible through jQuery.fn.myPlugin() instead of jQuery.myPlugin()?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've got this simple bit of code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.flyInModal = function() {
        alert('fly in?');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I can access it from the console by doing `jQuery.fn.flyInModal()`, but if i try `jQuery.flyInModal()` it just returns:

```
TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'flyInModal'
```

*Edit:* `jQuery.prototype.flyInModal()` also works.

Reading through [the doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) i should be able to access it this way. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery plugin added by extending `$.fn`, it is applicable to a jQuery object. That is,

```
$("#selector").flyInModal();
```

This applies `flyInModal` to the set of matched elements.

A jQuery function generally available is defined by extending `$`. That is,

```
$.flyInModal();
```

In your case, you are interested in the former.

Comment: Oh that clears things up! Thank you, i'll accept in a few mins!